# C# sha256 into PHP

Tags: c#, php, ascii, sha256

I've got a table of hashes and salts previously created by by another company. The hash was done in C# and the hash method is sha256. The logic behind this is `sha256(password+salt)`.

An example of inputs:

```
password = 'rosnicka'
salt     = 'zxwqTy+XjaY=' 
hash     = '3jdt1+JL3MPmjYr2OoXdoUwNfuweuDCZa8/3g7SfsNg='
```

When I tried to run a hashing function in PHP

the output of this is 
`"1125ed47a7aa11bc1c54c841b5eb7a6e72aa8ad27e010e6e25baa5b2a86cffb3"`

I get the same results using only hashing calculators

I contacted them to find out what I'm doing wrong. They told me, that are storing ASCII version of the hash in the database. What should I do in order to get the same hash in PHP or what to do in order to convert their hash to the original sha256 hash?

thanks a lot!

Comment: The C# hash has been Base64 encoded (so is the salt so it may be Base64 decoded before being applied), in php you have a hex representation of the bytes. Base64 encode the PHP hash result, if it does not match Base64 decode the salt, append the bytes and Base64 encode the result.

Comment: @AlexK. yeah but doesn't there have to be more to it? Base64 gives you a larger output than input, while in the example above the expected hash is only 44 chars - vs 64 chars in a sha256 hash.

Comment: No, 44 chars is reasonable, Base64 would be smaller - its 64 chars because 2 chars are used to visually represent each byte in that string, the hash length is half that.

Comment: I'll try that out! thanks. But they literally say they use ASCII which is instead of base64 shorter, which implies that they don't use base64.

Comment: By ASCII they mean they are using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rosnicka");` as opposed to the Unicode equivalent.

Comment: And the salt does need to be decoded: http://ideone.com/jZCmjc

Comment: ok, they talk about the final hash. so does it mean they do Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rocnickazxwqTy+XjaY=");

Comment: No, the link above is the correct C# code you need to port to PHP, convert the password, as an ascii string, to an array of bytes - append the bytes from Base64 decoding the salt - hash the result - Base64 encode it,

Comment: it is very correct sir!! Thanks a lot!. I don't mean to be lazy or anything but I'd pay with GOLD if somebody could help me port it to PHP. I've got very little time to do this :( but anyways I'm greatfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alex K said:

```
base64_encode(hash('sha256', 'rosnicka'.base64_decode('zxwqTy+XjaY='), true));
```

will do the trick

Comment: man! I love you:) I've tried to reproduce the C# code line by line but I've failed. Why don't I need to convert everything into array of bytes?

Comment: @AdamBednár the 'true' parameter will let hash() output bytes. You don't have to convert everything to bytes, but just make sure you concatenate same type of variables (password is plain string, while the salt is base64 encoded)

Comment: Please mark answer as selected if you appreciate help @AdamBednár